# How to call authenticated external API in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on an application where data will be coming from external api **http://finhelp/getStockDetails**

How do I call an bearer token authenticated external API from Laravel 5?

Comment: With Guzzle: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [Guzzle HTTP client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html).

First, have your token ready:

```
$token = 'someToken';
```

Create a Guzzle HTTP client with a base URI:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://foo.com/api/']);
```

Next, prepare your headers and include the Authorization header. Note that we simply concatenate 'Bearer ' and $token (include the space between them). In this example we also set the 'Accept' header to 'application/json', which is a common case:

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,        
    'Accept'        => 'application/json',
];
```

Next, use your $client to send a request to https://foo.com/api/bar. Include your headers in the request:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'bar', [
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
```